# Split string data on a string match

Tags: xml, swift, trim, truncate

I'm working with some xml and I'd like to clean it up before I parse it. What i'd like to do specifically, is take the data (example below) and match it on the string "`<data>`" and then trim everything before it leaving the node in tact. Then I would match on the string "`</data>`" and truncate everything after it, once again leaving the matched node in tact.

**Turning this:**

```
<dwml>
   <head>
      <child></child>
   </head>
   <data>
      <child></child>
      <child></child>
   </data>
   <more></more>
</dwml>
```

**into this:**

```
<data>
   <child></child>
   <child></child>
</data>
```

### My Question:

While I am sure there is a way to do this, I don't know where to start. Could someone could *point me in the right direction* **or** better yet *provide an example*? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use componentsSeparatedByString to isolate your elements as follow:

```
let xmlString = "<dwml><head><child></child></head><data><child></child><child></child></data><more></more></dwml>"

func filterData(input: String) -> String {
    return "<data>" + input.componentsSeparatedByString("<data>").last!.componentsSeparatedByString("</data>").first! + "</data>"
}

filterData(xmlString) // "<data><child></child><child></child></data>"
```

You can also use rangeOfString to find the range of your string:

```
func findData(input: String) -> String {
    if let startIndex = input.rangeOfString("<data>", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil, locale: nil)?.startIndex {
        if let endIndex = input.rangeOfString("</data>", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil, locale: nil)?.endIndex {
            return input.substringWithRange(startIndex..<endIndex)
        }
    }
    return ""
}

findData(xmlString)  // "<data><child></child><child></child></data>"
```

Comment: wow, what an excellent answer, I literally just dropped that in my project and it worked. thank you Leonardo!

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Actually there was an extra componentsSeparatedByString that you should remove